# Creating parameter named text files C#

Tags: c#, directory, filenames, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have to create a directory and then a text file inside this directory with name come from parameter. E.g. `_year` is a parameter and I tried as:

```
var _root = "C:\\Users\\~\\DirichletProcessClustering\\Results";
var _clusterFilename = _year.ToString() + "cluster.txt";
var _path = Path.Combine(_root, _year.ToString(), _clusterFilename);  

if(!Directory.Exists(_path))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(_path);
}

// output topk file
TextWriter _twClus = File.CreateText(_path);   
foreach (// loop )  
{ 
   _twClus.WriteLine("Cluster");  
   //... rest of the implementation...
}
```

This code is creating a folder named `2005` at specified path and then inside this folder, there is another folder named `2005cluster.txt` while I want to create a text file named `2005cluster.txt` inside folder `2005`.

- Where I am getting wrong in creating correct folder and file names?
- An UnauthorizedAccessException generated at undermentioned line of
  code i.e. *access is denied*. Why is this happening?

`TextWriter _twClus = File.CreateText(_path);`

Comment: So all you want to do is create a directory, then a file inside that directory you just created?

Comment: Yeah but directory with year name and file also with year name plus "cluster" for example `2005\2005cluster.txt` where 2005 is directory and 2005cluster.txt is file

Comment: So are you getting the current year from Windows, or allowing the user to pass it in?

Comment: Yeah it is a method which accepts `_year` as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are defining fileName separately, You could try this:

```
var _root = "C:\\Users\\~\\DirichletProcessClustering\\Results";
var _clusterFilename = _year.ToString() + "cluster.txt";
var _path = Path.Combine(_root, _year.ToString());  

if(!Directory.Exists(_path))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(_path);
}

// output topk file
TextWriter _twClus = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(_path, _clusterFilename));   
foreach (// loop )  
{ 
   _twClus.WriteLine("Cluster");  
   //... rest of the implementation...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this so that your path has a slash before the file name:

```
var _root = "C:\\Users\\~\\DirichletProcessClustering\\Results\\";
```

Comment: `Path.Combine()` does the hard work that you are describing.

Comment: It wasn't asked what answered here whereas two bullets are the questions asked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file name from your path as:

```
var _path = Path.Combine(_root, _year.ToString());
```

For defining the filename you have to modify this line of code as:

```
TextWriter _twClus = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(_path, _clusterFilename));
```